# Play audio file when keyboard is pressed

Tags: python, os.system

I have the following code in which I capture the user input and then I want to parse it and evaluate each character in string using ASCII code to play a certain .mp3 file:

The problem is that this code works only for the first character. For example, if I have the input as `ab` I only hear the audio file for `a` and not `b`

```
import os 

wrd=raw_input("Please write something: ") 
wrd=(str(wrd)).lower() 
wrd=list(wrd) 
i=0 
print (wrd[0:len(wrd):1]) 

for wrd[i] in wrd:
    print wrd[i]
    if ord((wrd[i]))==97:
        os.system("start C:/Users/letters/a(1).mp3")
        i+=1
    if ord((wrd[i]))==98:
        os.system("start C:/Users//letters/b(1).mp3")
        i+=1
```

Comment: you use `for` in strange way. Use `for char in wrd:` and you will no need `i`

Comment: what you hear if you input `ba` ? maybe file is broken, or you use wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mp3 file name always follow the path "letter(1),mp3" you can do something like:

```
import os

wrd = input("Please write something: ")
wrd = wrd.lower()

for char in wrd:
   try:
       os.system("start " + char +'(1).mp3')
   except:
       ValueError
```

otherwise you can use a dictionary and fill it with the right filename for each letter:

```
db = {
   'a': 'C:/Users//letters/a(1).mp3',
   'b': 'C:/Users//letters/b(1).mp3'
   # etc
}
...
   try:
       os.system("start " + db[char])
...
```

Comment: It works but I guess is should ut a time.sleep() somewhere because is very fast in you can hear only the last letter of the string for example if the input si : ab I can hear only the b . Thanks